# Relatively compact of minimizing sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces

Let 
$$
E(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb R^n} |\nabla u|^2-\frac{1}{p+1}|u|^{p+1} dx
$$
where $p$ is a positive constant. Define
$$
I_\mu=\inf\{E(u): u\in H^2(\mathbb R^n), ||u||_{L^2}^2=\mu\}.
$$
Assume $\{u_n\}$ is a minimizing sequence of $I_\mu$, i.e.
$$
u_n\in H^2(\mathbb R^n),~~   ||u||_{L^2}^2=\mu,~~
E(u_n)\rightarrow I_\mu.
$$
**Why there are $\{y_n\}\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $\{u_n(\cdot+y_n)\}$ is relatively compact 
in $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ ?**

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This question is a doubt when I read the 552th page of  *Cazenave, T.; Lions, Pierre-Louis*, [**Orbital stability of standing waves for some nonlinear Schrödinger equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01403504), Commun. Math. Phys. 85, 549-561 (1982). [ZBL0513.35007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0513.35007).

Comment: Maybe your question is related to the concentration-compactness principle.

Comment: @Rigel   Could you talk about it detail ? I know the concentration-compactness principle. But how to use it ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to help you. My observation is related to the "sperimental" fact that, almost every time one gets a sequence of the form $\{u_n(\cdot + y_n)\}$, then at some point the concentration-compactness principle comes into action.

Comment: @Rigel  Thanks your hint too.